# Pandas.read_csv "unexpected end of data" Error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read a dataset using pd.read_csv() am getting an error. Excel can open it just fine.

`reviews = pd.read_csv('br.csv')` gives the error ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 312074

`reviews = pd.read_csv('br.csv', engine='python', encoding='utf-8')` returns ParserError: unexpected end of data

What can I do to fix this?

Edit:
This is the dataset - https://www.kaggle.com/gnanesh/goodreads-book-reviews

Comment: Can you share the data? I'm guessing that, if you were to open it in a text editor, you'd see that there are unbalanced quotation marks.

Comment: Or maybe just share line 312074 of that file

Comment: This is the data: https://www.kaggle.com/gnanesh/goodreads-book-reviews

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For me adding this fixed it:

`error_bad_lines=False`

It just skips the last line. 
So instead of

`reviews = pd.read_csv('br.csv', engine='python', encoding='utf-8')`

`reviews = pd.read_csv('br.csv', engine='python', encoding='utf-8', error_bad_lines=False)`

Comment: `error_bad_lines` is now deprecated, so you can instead use `on_bad_lines` e.g. `on_bad_lines='warn'` or `on_bad_lines='skip`' to not warn or `on_bad_lines='error'` to generate an exception

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I don't want to skip lines, since my task is required to count the number of data records in the csv file.
The solution that works for me is using the Quote_None from csv library.
I try this from reading on some websites that I did not remember, but it works.

To describe my case, previouly I have the error: EOF ....
Then I tried using the parameter engine='python'. But that introduce another bug for next step of using the dataframe. 
Then I try quoting=csv.Quote_None, and it's ok now.
I hope this helps

```
import csv    
read_file = read_csv(full_path, delimiter='~', encoding='utf-16 BE', header=0, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```